# Regular Expression for valid domains

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

```
Regex(@"@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Using the above, I want to pass only values like @gmail.com, @xyz.edu, @co.uk etc... 
But I find that the values like abc@gmail.com (valid email ids) also pass through.

What should I modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `^` in front of the `@`.

By the way, why the `{2,4}` in the end. `.travel` is a valid top level domain as well.

Comment: as is museum and a few other longer top level domains. And then there's domain names with extended characters as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Answer (score 2):

Domain cannot start with `-` character.

`^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$`

---

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.cnn.com/some_link/document.htm");
string url = uri.Host.ToString();
```